# how can mercury thermometer measure temperatures above 640 k?

Tags: thermodynamics

I know it's by filling the space above mercury with nitrogen at high pressure, but how will it help?

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase "phase diagram"?

Comment: @dmckee yes i know.

Comment: @dmckee yes i'm familiar with it

Comment: You're looking at a situation with gaseous nitrogen, liquid mercury and mercury vapor in equilibrium at steadily increasing temperature, but mercury vapor's pressure increases faster with increasing temperature than that of the liquid phase. Then you sit down with a engineering grade phase diagram and start working the figures.

Comment: @dmckee I'm sorry I'm not able to get you. can you please explain with a little more detail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This graph shows the vapour pressure of mercury as a function of temperature:

[image: Vapour pressure of mercury]

([image from this article](http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~eandrei/389/NISTIR.6643.pdf))

The relevance of this is that a liquid boils when its vapour pressure is equal to the external pressure, so the graph effectively shows the boiling point as a function of pressure. The graph shows that if you pressurise the thermometer it raises the boiling point of the mercury and allows you to use the thermometer to measure higher temperatures.